# Are the rims for 195/60R15 the same as rims for 195/65R15

Tags: ford, tires, wheels

I need to replace one rim on my ford focus the tires I have on it currently are 195/60R15, I have another tire on a rim the numbers on the tire are 195/65R15 can I mount the 195/60R15 tire onto the rim that has the 195/65R15 tire.

To put it simply does the R15 mean 15 inch rims?

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: "To put it simply does the R15 mean 15 inch rims" Yes. 65 is slightly wider than 60, but will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it mount?  Yes.
Are they the same?  Maybe.
There are a few other specification to the rim other than the diameter.
Width
Backspacing
Number of lug holes
Lug hole spacing
Center bore diameter

You should be quickly see if they are the same lug pattern measuring the distance between the lug holes.  Given that the other rim came from a similar style car (fwd), the backspacing should be very similar.  If you know what the rim came off of you can look this up and verify.  The tire width is the same, so the rim width should be the same (should be 6").

Answer (score 2):

Ummmm.  The *rim* you can most likely use, the tire you cannot.

Unless you buy three more to match.  There's a lot of speculation about using the *tire*, even though that was not the OP's question.

On a driven axle this will cause a horrible differential action, and eventually do some damage to the drivetrain.  Even on a non-driven axle, you will be changing handling vectors, weight distribution, roll couples, and brake torque.  Not to mention odd tire wear on the larger ("taller") tire.  The result is only desirable when setting stagger for a short track event, where you *want* the weird handling characteristics a taller set of outside tires provide.

Very highly not recommended to use a different *tire*.  Minor differences in the rim are probably not worrysome, unless the offset causes rubbing,

Answer (score 1):

195 is the with of the tire in millimeters(mm). 60 or 65 is the percent of the sidewall height relative to the width also in mm. At 60 the sidewall height is 117 mm, at 65 the sidewall is 126.75mm. A difference of 9.75 mm. A change of diameter of 19.5 mm or a hair over 3/4 ". Change in circumference of tire 2.355 " . 195 mm is 7.67" wide.

I wonder if that difference in circumference  would affect speedometer accuracy? I'll leave that for the mathematicians and engineers to squabble about.

P refers to the type of vehicle -Passenger car, R is for Radial tire.

As mentioned by rpmerf the number of bolts and bolt circle should match you vehicles requirement.

Answer (score -1):

First thing you need to do is learn the basics of Rims (Fælge) , Tires (Dæk) and the Combination result of a wheel (hjul).

The 4 rims and 4 tires on a vehicle MUST be identical in dimænsjens..
You can easily find a rim that you can mount, because to mount only requires the correct Bolt / Lug number and pattern / mæsjerment..

BUT BE SERIOUS.. ONLY MOUNT 4 IDENTICAL DIMÆNSJEN RIMS...

Take my family car as an examp., a Fiat Panda III from 2012...
It uses a HjulNav structure (Wheel Flange) with 4 Bolts in a 98mm Circle Diameter, with a center hole of 58,1mm and can variate from 32 to 38mm in Offset / backspacing, ET (Einpress Tiefe)..
Those MUST BE FOLLOWED..
What you can choose within is usually 14, 15 or 16 inch rims, or on bigger cars, likewise, 17, 18 or 19 inch..

What you must to is look up the technical info on YOUR CAR.
INSTRUKTION MANUAL, ONLINE Wheel merchants info tables where you write in your license plate or Car Model exactly and get info onscreen.
Also, very important to unmount your wheels and look on them. It can be either on the front or back, there will be the dimensions in this code ,,, 6J15H2 F498 ET35... NUMBERS WILL BE DIFFERENT ON DIFFERENT CARS...

6J means a 6 inch WIDE rim with a J architecture...
15 is the rim diameter again in inches.
H2 is also rim architecture, don't worry about that but keep all 4 rims in same architecture profile.. They will be automatically in 99pct cases.

F4 is a code used for 4 bolt setups in Fiat and other brands' models.

ET35 is again the backspace. The length from the CENTER OF THE WIDTH OF THE RIM TILL THE CONTACT FLANGE, HJULNAVVET, WHERE THE RIM MEETS THE CAR.

In 195/60R15 the 60 is NOT the percentage OF THE SIDEWALL HEIGHT.
It is THE PERCENTAGE OF THE TIRES WIDTH WHIIIIICH EQUALS THE DIMENSION OF THE SIDEWALL Height.

If you drove on 195/100 tires they would be 195mm wide and have sidewalls of 195mm height.

Now, only use your spare rims with the present rims once you've correctly checked all this to be equal measures and once you inspected that it has no structural damage or even minor damage to the area where the tire bead will settle and make the airtight seal..

Try to purchase Aluminium rims with a professional lacquer finish. The smooth lacquer is very important, the COLOR is NOT.
Get ALL info on rims before you send money to the seller . Best to see it in reality first..
Steel rims will rust out from within, slowly destroying its own ability to hold the airtight seal. The water on them will soak up rust and that may spread to other places in the break and suspension system..

I personally sprayed my almost new Steel rims for the Panda with quality Zink paint and still they could not hold back the iron in the steel from rusting out thru BOTH the original black lacquer paint on the steel AND the Zink layer..

Comment: "The 4 rims and 4 tires on a vehicle MUST be identical in dimænsjens" This is not true, there are vehicles that use different front rims and tires from the rear ones.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please realize, this site is not a typical forum. We are an English only, Q&A site. Please take [the Tour](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help Center](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help) for how Stack Exchange works. I have deleted your extraneous comments which you've left as answers. Also, when answering, actually read the question and keep your answer specific to the question at hand. You have a lot of superfluous comments within your "answer" which don't fit, plus, quite a lot of it is just completely wrong.